# Correct way to fill shape with image cropped from sprite

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

I am slightly confused about the "correct" way in KineticJS to fill a shape with partial images (crops) from a combined image file (sprite).

Seems like one can either use fillPatternImage with a defined offset, which seems to draw the complete image, albeit with the rest of the image invisible. I only got acceptable performance after I moved those shapes to an extra layer as my sprite is relatively large and the impact of not cropping correctly decreased the fps dramatically.

All alternatives that I have found use the attribute "fill" with another attribute "image" in it, but this seems to result in black background every time.

Using an Image-shape would help, but is rarely usable since my shapes are seldom rectangular.

Since the KineticJS-documentation does not mention specifying crop coordinates ("just" offset, w/o width and height), what is the absolute correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The absolute "absolute correct way" would depend on the platform and your particular code, but.

Have you looked at sprites? http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-sprite-tutorial/.

To mask simple animated sprites I'd use this in adition of plain javascript after each draw.

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
```

The performance of drawImage with composite operations is better than drawing shapes manually on webkit, at least.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I didn't mean sprites as in multiple related images (for an animation), I meant sprites as in multiple independent images that just share a file to decrease the number of GET requests. As far as I understand "destination-in", it wouldn't help me because the previous images need to be visible, too :)

Comment: I see, in canvas, unlike other technologies like WebGL(openGL anyway), sharing sprites on a single sprite-sheet would still require you to make one draw per sprite instead of one draw per sprite-sheet.

Anyway, in KineticJS filling image objects with fillPatternImage will draw the whole image on each sprite at the object creating, but further updates or moves of the sprite won't redraw the full image object.

The 'destination-in' approach would be meant to be used when drawing  onto an offscreen canvas prior to the final canvas ;)